# IBAction repeated on all buttons - swift

Tags: swift, loops, button, ibaction

I created 2 buttons for 2 actions in my code and I put some `print()` in order to check when I am entering the button action.
The issue is that I am entering `Button1` after clicking (and executing code) on `Button2`. Here is my code, I do not get it..

```
@IBOutlet weak var Button1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var Button2: UIButton!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

/* ---------------- city picker ------------- */

@IBAction func p_cityButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    if p_cityPicker.hidden == false {
        p_cityPicker.hidden = true
        CityDoneButton.hidden = true
        CityCancelButton.hidden = true
    }
    else {
        var pickerData: [[String]] = [[String]]()
        p_cityPicker.hidden = false
        self.p_cityPicker.delegate = self
        self.p_cityPicker.dataSource = self

    pickerData = [["Ashdod", "Ashkelon", "Jerusalem", "Netanya", "Tel-Aviv"]]
    CityDoneButton.hidden = false
    CityCancelButton.hidden = false
        print("Button2")
    }

}


/* ---------------- Date Picker ------------- */
@IBAction func d_aliyahButton(sender: AnyObject) {
if d_aliyahDatePicker.hidden == false {
    d_aliyahDatePicker.hidden = true
    DateDoneButton.hidden = true
    DateCancelButton.hidden = true
}
else{
d_aliyahDatePicker.hidden = false
d_aliyahDatePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Date
DateDoneButton.hidden = false
DateCancelButton.hidden = false
print("Button1")
}
```

If I click on Button1 I have

> Button1

If I click on Button2 I have

> Button1
>
> Button2

I do not want to go through `Button1` when I click on `Button2`.
Any idea where my issue is?

[Links on ctrl+click on button2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpiqd.png)

Thank you!

Comment: It sounds like you have Button2 wired up to both @IBActions.  Control-click on the button2 in the Storyboard and delete the connection to Button1 function.

Comment: If you have more code in button1 and button2 functions, you should show us. Or try with just this code and see if the result is the same

Comment: I just edited my post with the complete code. I named Button1 and Button2 because in the UI Button1 is before Button2.

Comment: vacawama you were right. I did it and now it is working well. I could also simplify the code! Thank you guys! Have a nice day!